# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: azure

I have a fresh MVC5 project made from Visual Studio 2013, which works fine when I try to launch it locally. However, when I publish to my Azure website, I get this front page:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

And the stack trace:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, >Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
>      System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

I have version 3.0.0 of Microsoft.Owin installed, and it says the same thing in my Web.config and packages.config. How can I fix this?

Comment: `Update-Package -ProjectName myproject`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try to :

1. Upgrading `Microsoft.Owin.Security` from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0
2. Upgrading `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0
3. Upgrading `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` from 2.1.0 to 3.0.0

After I have upgraded above packages, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Yup, I figured this out a while ago and forgot about this question. Just reinstall whatever package it is asking for. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: I had newer versions, same problem. Getting them all to the same version helped.

Comment: Yep, worked for me, upgraded to version 3.0 and error disappear

Comment: how do we upgrade can someone provide link

Comment: Late to the party but to upgrade, one way is to use the Package Manager Console. Type "update-package Microsoft.Owin.Security" (without the quotes) and the next two as listed above.

Comment: This doesn't work if your project has references to features on in 2.1 like ISecureDataFormat<>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by following way

1. Navigate to **tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..**
2. In NuGet solutions click on the **installed tab**.
3. On the search bar type **Owin**. You can see all Owin packages in there.
4. Compare package versions in both **NuGet solution** and **Web.Config** file.
5. Rename **newVersion="x.x.x.x"** in web config according to versions in Nuget solution.

Below versions must consider in both **NuGet solution** and **Web.Config**

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Microsoft.Owin
```