# Visual Studio 2015 New .NET MVC Project Error: "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, visual-studio-2015

Question: How do I create a new project without this (authentication-related) error?

Symptoms: The new (completely unaltered) project does not build (see Build Errors image).

Error replication steps:

1. Open Visual Studio (my version = 2015)
2. File
3. New
4. Project (see Project image for settings)
5. OK
6. Error (see Error image for alert)
7. OK
8. Build
9. Build Errors (see Build Errors image)

Note: the error only appears when authentication is included in the new project and appears to be related to authentication because I receive several warnings and errors concerning authentication-related dependencies (see Dependencies image for warnings).

I've tried...

1. Closing and re-opening Visual Studio
2. Uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio

Project

[image: Project Image]

Error

[image: Error Image]

Dependencies

[image: Dependencies]

Build Errors

[image: Build Errors]

Some errors (if the image is hard to read)

1. CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SignInManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. CS0246  The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3. CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4. CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your screenshot shows many assembly references missing. Did you run NuGet update and package restore?

Comment: No luck after nuget update and package restore. See comment below or this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432720/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-owin-security-cookies-or-one-of-its) answer for what eventually worked. Thanks for your comment nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshots you attached are clearly showing that you have broken references for asp.net identity framework.

You can try removing those references and install the nuget package again.

Here is the package name : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it pushed me toward an eventual workaround. But my question is how to create new project w/o the error **not** how to fix a broken project. Steps for workaround: 1) manually install all missing packages as @Majid suggests (your build should now succeed). 2) if F5 produces an error related to Microsoft.Owin.Security, upgrade the version from 2.1.0 to 3.1.0 (this answer helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432720/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-owin-security-cookies-or-one-of-its). Authentication should now work...

Comment: ...but upon creating a new project, I need to repeat the steps above to resolve authentication dependency-related errors.

Comment: May be you are having some famework issues on your machine. You can try re-installing the asp.net MVC framework which comes with Visual Studio 2015 community edition using web plateform installer.