# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth' or one of its dependencies. The process can not access the file because the file is in use by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

I can't understand the reason of error

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the part "file is in use by another process"

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432720/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-owin-security-cookies-or-one-of-its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for that error is: the said assembly `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` is locked by some other process. Means, at current some other process already using it and your application is trying to load the same.

Most probably you application is already running and you are trying to build your solution. solution: End your application and then close and re-open your solution again.

Comment: When i close the project and open again this error sometimes removed and project is running successfully, but not at all time.Is this a error connected with database, or connectionstring?

Comment: @ZhanVardanyan, NO, as said in answer, some other process is already using the dll and so your application not able to load it. Another solution would be: close and re-open visual studio altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that the whole assembly couldn't be loaded in current `AppDomain` because it's already locked by another process.

You'll need to check if you're using in any other project and it's already taken...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth' is attached by some other process.Its probably because your solution is already attached with other process. 
Go to task manager close the operation manually and then try to build it again.